# Calculate time duration between differents records in a table based on datetimes

Tags: sql-server, view, calculated-columns

For the question, Let's say I have a table that holds the following data :

1) Name
2) Mood
3) DateTime

I could insert records like :

```
Andy    Happy    '11.06.2012 - 14.06.07' -- Inserted on 11.06.2012 @ 19:12.32
Arthur  Angry    '11.06.2012 - 15.06.57' -- Inserted on 11.06.2012 @ 17:12.32
Andy    Sad      '11.06.2012 - 14.34.05' -- Inserted on 11.06.2012 @ 17:12.32
Arthur  Happy    '11.06.2012 - 13.34.05' -- Inserted on 11.06.2012 @ 14:12.32
```

I would like to get the "duration" information related to these moods changes !

My table holds thousands of hundred or records and I cannot afford having a process that takes too much time. What would be the best way of calculating this ?

- Trigger "After insert", filling a "Duration" column ?
- Stored procedure that fill a previously created "Duration" column ?
- Calculated column ?
- A view (I already tried that and it takes more than 2 seconds to display, which is totally unacceptable)
- Another idea ?

Thanks for your help !

Important edit :
The mood records arrive grouped into packet and we cannot be sure that already inserted records have smaller dates! (see the above comments next to my records)

Comment: How about usinga pivot query to get your data into the same row, and then use that query as a sub  where you can then just do the math.

Comment: Can you have the mood start time & mood end time as separate columnS? If yes then you can use TO_CHAR() function to find the difference.

Comment: You can also put indexes on views (though they are some big restrictions)

Comment: Don't use a trigger. Why do you need to store redundant data that you can derive at query time? If you really think you need to store it, why not add the delta as part of the insert of a new row (all it has to do is grab the existing MAX([datetime]) for that same user)?

Comment: @Limey how would you construct an indexed view that answers this query faster?

Comment: @munna `TO_CHAR()` is oracle, this question is tagged sql server, but yes, having columns for start time and end time makes sense to me

Comment: @AaronBertrand: He is saying he already contructed the view, but it's slow.  Just hoping that an index might speed up his situation.

Comment: @paul for SQL server you can use TO_CHAR equivalent like SUBSTRING(CONVERT()) function

Comment: @Limey Understood, but I fail to see how you could create a view for this specific query that would be a candidate for an index.

Comment: @munna I have absolutely no idea how TO_CHAR() or SUBSTRING(CONVERT()) would help make this query faster.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'm assuming he has more than just the three columns on his table, otherwise even the table wouldn't be able to have an index or even properly joined to another table, let alone a view.

Comment: @Limey I have no idea what you're talking about. The problem is that he needs a MAX aggregate or something similar (e.g. the most recent time of the last mood change), which can't be a part of an indexed view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible SQL version:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Time])As RowNum
    , *
    FROM @table T
)
SELECT 
    DiffSec=DATEDIFF(s,[Time],(SELECT [Time] FROM CTE c2 WHERE c2.[Name]=CTE.[Name] AND c2.RowNum=CTE.RowNum+1))
    , [Name]
    , Mood
    , [Time]
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY [Name],[RowNum]
```

Result:

```
DiffSec Name    Mood    Time
1678    Andy    Happy   2012-06-11 14:06:07.000
NULL    Andy    Sad     2012-06-11 14:34:05.000
5228    Arthur  Angry   2012-06-11 14:06:57.000
NULL    Arthur  Happy   2012-06-11 15:34:05.000
```

Your test data:

```
declare @table table(name varchar(10),mood varchar(10),time datetime);
insert into @table values('Andy','Happy',convert(datetime,'11.06.2012 14:06:07',104));
insert into @table values('Arthur','Angry',convert(datetime,'11.06.2012 14:06:57',104));
insert into @table values('Andy','Sad',convert(datetime,'11.06.2012 14:34:05',104));
insert into @table values('Arthur','Happy',convert(datetime,'11.06.2012 15:34:05',104));
```

---

**Edit** Self-Joining a `CTE` seems to be a very bad idea (*"[If you self join the CTE it will kill you](http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-programming/379487-cte-vs-temp-tables.html)"*). I've tested my query with 500000 records in a temporary table and cancelled the query after 30 minutes.

Here's a much faster approach(4 seconds for all) using a sub-query (with your commented schema):

```
SELECT T.*
    ,(SELECT DATEDIFF(s,MAX(T2.Time),T.Time)
      FROM dbo.Temp T2
      WHERE T2.HE_Id = T.HE_Id
          AND T2.Time < T.Time
    ) AS DiffSec
FROM dbo.Temp AS T
ORDER BY HE_Id ,DiffSec
```

Comment: And with Denali / SQL 2012, you now have LEAD() and LAG() with partitions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer ! I tried it, by simply copy-pasting it and adapating it on my table. My table actually store more than 500'000 entries and this query has been running for nearly 10 minutes without giving us an answer... I'll try and simplying a bit but looks like it's too heavy... Note: We have a 16 core server with 32 go of ram... :)

Comment: ... but, on the example you gave, it's exactely what we do need ! The last records have null entry on the DiffSec common, except for the process duration, it looks perfect !

Comment: @AndyM: 500k records is relatively little. Have you [proper indices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650692.aspx#scalenethowto03_topic5) on your table? Are you storing the name of the user or just the foreign-key(recommended)?

Comment: @AndyM: Try to create this or a similar index on your table: `CREATE INDEX idxNameTime ON YourTable([Name], [Time]);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I tried both of your attempt but without any success... I should be missing something, my last attempt lasted more than 2 hours !! and i stopped it before getting any results... My table fileds are : Id(int), S_Id(int), HE_Id(int), Code(int), Time(DateTime), deleted(bit) and I have a index on S_Id, HE_Id and Time.

Comment: @AndyM: What are the name- and the mood-fields?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Name = HE_Id and Mood = S_Id... I've created a Test_SO table and populated it with my data, how can I give it to you so you can give it a go with my own data ?

Comment: @AndyM:  _"If you self join the CTE it will kill you"_ ;-) Edited my answer to provide another approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Oh well :) Your last proposition looks really good... On our table, the results appears after around 9.2 seconds ! I'll give it some more tests but it looks great ! Thanks a whole lot !